# global sections of structure sheaf of a projective scheme X over a field k?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

Some may have already asked this question.
What are the global sections of structure sheaf of a projective scheme $X$ over a field $k$?

By Hartshorne *page 18, Chapter 1, Theorem 3.4*, global sections will be $k$ when $k$ is algebraically closed and $X$ in some $\mathbb P^n$ is a projective variety.

Could any one give a counter example for the case $k$ is not algebraically closed? 
(What will happen if $k=\mathbb R$, the real numbers, and $X=\mathrm{Proj}(\mathbb R[x,y] \mathop{/} {(x^2+y^2)})$ ?)

If $X$ is an integral projective scheme of finite dimension over $k$ (algebraically closed), then $X$ is a projective variety by Hartshorne *page 104, Chapter 2, Proposition 4.10*. And its global sections should be $k$. Do I need to fix some very ample sheaf to give an embedding to define its structure sheaf?

This is my first time to ask a question. Welcome any advice.

Thanks!

Comment: I edited your post directly. For any mathematical part, you must use $\LaTeX$ : it is much more readable. I *emphasized* the references. And the guy is Hartshorne, not Harsthorne. ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice and edition!

Comment: See Corollary 3.21 in Qing Liu's book _Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves_, Oxford University Press (2006).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $X/k$ is proper, integral, then $\Gamma(X, \mathcal O_X)$ will be a finite extension of $k$.

In the example you ask for, namely $X=\text{Proj}(\mathbf{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2))$ (graded with $x,y$ in degree $1$), the global sections of $\mathcal O_X$ will be (up to the choice of $x/y$ or $y/x$ as $i$) isomorphic to $\mathbf C$. This scheme is actually affine, isomorphic as an $\mathbf R$-scheme to $\text{Spec } \mathbf C$.

To answer your second question: if $X/k$ is a scheme, projective or not, then it has a structure sheaf by definition of a scheme. You do not need to fix an embedding into projective space. (Anyways, if $X/k$ is a projective scheme, then by definition, it *comes with* an embedding into projective space, so you don't need to fix one yourself.)

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering in the case that k is not algebraically closed, is it still true that negative degree line bundles do not have global section?

Comment: I think that finite type is part of the definition of proper :) Also, if the OP is curious, your claim about global sections of proper things being finite can be found in Liu--corollary 3.19. Of course, it also easier to see if one uses more sophisticated machinery

Comment: @AlexYoucis You are right, proper already implies finite type. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @user48537 You are welcome. If you have another question, you should post it separately.

Comment: @Bruno Joyal  I just thought that in the example X=Proj(R[x,y]/(x2+y2)), R-base of Ox is {1,x/y}, R-base of Ox(-1) is {1/x,1/y}. So Ox(-1) has global sections. Is it right? Thanks.

Comment: "then by definition, it comes with an embedding into projective space" is wrong! it just admits some, but a projective scheme is not a couple!